# Vuex reference not returning correct value

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am referencing a VueX getter in a object like so :

```
computed : {
    ...mapGetters(['activeLayer']),
}
```

The store getter looks like this :

```
getters : {
    activeLayer : state => state.views[state.activeView].layers[state.views[state.activeView].activeLayer]
}
```

I am then using a watch to monitor for changes:

```
created {
    var that = this;
    this.$store.watch( function(state) {return state.views[state.activeView].activeLayer}, 

        function() {
            console.log(that.activeLayer); // Returns initial value
            that.$store.state.views[this.$store.state.activeView].layers[this.$store.state.views[this.$store.state.activeView].activeLayer]; // Returns correct value
        }

    ,{ deep: true } )
}
```

The issue is that when the store changes `activeLayer` does not update to the new value.

How can I force `activeLayer` to update?

Comment: What is the code that changes `activeLayer`?  Getters are inherently reactive, there should be no need to force an update.

Comment: @Dan My thoughts too, but when I directly reference the active layer via this.$store.state ect. I get a different result to the activeState which is mapped with mapGetters.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`mapState`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) instead and watching for changing would be like this:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
```

```
computed: { ...mapState(['activeLayer']), }
```

```
watch: {
     activeLayer(newValue, oldValue) {
          console.log(newValue);
     }
},
```

Comment: Doesn't this take away the point of using a getter?  I want to shorten the extremely long state variable and use it in multiple components.

Comment: Since you want it to auto-update when the store changes and not get it only at the beginning, ``mapState`` is the way to go. You don't need to set a getter. And you can use this method wherever you want.

Comment: Makes sense, though how do I shortern the variable down to `activeLayer` and keep it reactive?

Comment: If you use ``mapState``, you can reference it as ``this.activeLayer`` and it will change normally on updates.

Comment: But activeLayer "is not" a top level or real property it's a dynamic object.